# Can't make multiple charts to work with highcharts

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to build a dashboard-like page using Highcharts. At this point i have four charts: two pies and two gauges. Please see following code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="dash-container">
        <div id="text">
            <div class="title">

            </div>
      </div>
        <div id="chars">
            <div id="gauge1"></div>
            <div id="pie1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dash-container">
        <div id="text">
            <div id="title">

            </div>
      </div>
        <div id="chars2">
            <div id="gauge2"></div>
            <div id="pie2"></div>
        </div>
</div>

    </div>
```

At the end of the "body" file i call the highcharts js scripts:

```
<script src="pie.js"></script>
<script src="gauge.js"></script>
<script src="pie2.js"></script>
<script src="gauge2.js"></script>
```

Everything looks fine. However, i am using the gauge example file that changes values in real time. Here is the code, from gauge.js:

```
setInterval(function() {
var point;

  point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
  inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
  newVal = point.y + inc;

  if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
      newVal = point.y - inc;
  }

  point.update(newVal);
}


}, 2000);
```

The problem is that the two gauges charts are not working properly. One is stuck (won't update the data) and the other one updates the data too fast. I think the problem is that the SetInterval(Function...) is implemented in both gauge1.js and gauge2.js but i am new to javascript and i can't really get how to fix it. 
Suggestions?
Would you also mind explaining a bit how functions works in javascript? I.e. Why this function somehow breakes the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: when defining the gauge chart there is a variable called "chartspeed", 
this variable has the same name in both charts, changed that to "chartspeed2"

```
 var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('gauge2', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
            title: null
```

and updated the gauge.js:

```
setInterval(function() {
var point;

  point = chartSpeed2.series[0].points[0];
  inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
  newVal = point.y + inc;

  if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
      newVal = point.y - inc;
  }

  point.update(newVal);
}


}, 2000);
```